# how to set input value in developer JSON before send

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, validation, schema

I have json data like this in that, I don't know were I have to set answer,

```
{
  "id": 1251,
  "name": "user_reported_systolic",
  "description": "This is the first of the 2 numbers displayed on your blood pressure meter",
  "label": "Systolic",
  "dataType": "NUMBER",
  "selectType": "NONE",
  "displayType": "TEXTBOX",
  "alwaysToday": true,
  "value":
  {
      "string": "",
      "number": "",
      "keys": "",
      "date": ""
  },
  "entryDate": "",
  "expectedRange": {
      "Low":3,
      "High": 5
  }
}
```

I created input field to fetch number after that I don't know were I have to set my input value to this JSON, because I have to send this JSON data to Developer once input field success.

In future I need to create dynamic input field based on JSON, that may be text area, radio, checkbox, etc

Answer (score 0):

After get value from  input jest store again in your json

---

```
"value":
  {
      "string": "",
      "number": "",
      "keys": "",
      "date": ""
  },
```

---

In you getting string store in string ,if is number store in number, if its radio (or) check box store your key and value in there,

Key and value based on some calculation, So contact with your back-end developer